# ECC Curve Modulus

Tags: security, rsa, elliptic-curve

What is the modulus of an ECC P-256 key?  Would it be 32 bytes?  I seem to only be able to sign/encrypt a 32 byte data buffer with this key.

For RSA, I know that a 1024 bit RSA key has a modulus of 128 bytes.  For ECC, I'm confused about what "P" means.

Comment: "I seem to only be able to sign/encrypt a 32 byte data buffer with this key" sounds really weird. How did you manage to do that? -- You can sign unlimited message sizes since you hash the message as part of ECDSA. As for encryption, ECC usually isn't used for encryption directly, it's used as key-exchange (Diffie-Hellman) together with symmetric encryption such as AES.

Comment: Right, you are signing a hash of the message.  What I'm trying to figure out is what length I want the hash to be for a given ECDSA key.  It sounds like it should be a 32 byte hash if its an P-256 key.

Comment: BTW, I don't know !*#$ about cryptography and I'm just trying to understand enough to get something done...  So things that I'm saying probably make no sense, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

You should read more about ECC. P-256 curve(s) are based on 256-bit underlying field, however this is not the order of base point.
RSA has much simpler math and can directly encrypt/decrypt data, you should never compare RSA and ECDSA.

Answer (score 2):

The modulus `p` of the X9.62/SECG curve over a 256 bit prime field is

> 0xFFFFFFFFF00000001000000000000000000000000FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF

You can find this information in `ec_curve.c` of the OpenSSL library.

And, yes, `p` is a 32-byte number. In ECC, while `p` usually represents the modulus of a prime field, `P` usually represents a point on the elliptic curve, where `P = [k]G`, `0<k<p-1` and `G` is the generator of the curve.